# Turn a for loop into a static array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am working on a backbone app, and was provided some sample code, the provider made the data into a for loop which generates a number, I don't want that. I need to enter in player names like Kobe, Lebron etc not player_1, player_2.

```
//generate 20 players
for(var i=1; i <= 20; i++) {
    players.add({
        id: i,
        name: 'player_' + i,
        score: Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+20)
    });
}

//generate 4 teams, and assign players to them at the same time...
for(var i=1; i <= 4; i++) {
    teams.add({
        id: i,
        name: 'team_' + i,
        players: new App.Collections.Players(players.filter(function(player) {
          return (player.id <= i*5 && player.id > (i-1)*5);
        }))
    });
}
```

I am not sure how I can turn this into a static piece so I can enter player names manually (name: mike, name: john) not that format of course but I dont want (name: player_1, name: player_2).

I console.logged `teams.toJSON()` I get the objects in the console, but I cant figure out how to get the raw JSON data so I can see how to structure a hardcoded JSON array.

Comment: Loop an array of names instead of just numbers?

Comment: That did cross my mind, but I am pretty new to javascript, and I am not sure how to create an array of names then implement it into the loop... This could have been the question itself, but I wouldn't mind writing it statically. I am open to all solutions, if you could kindly provide a sample maybe a fiddle, post it as an answer then I can award you.

Comment: `names=['mike','john']; for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) ...`. Same as any other language that has these basic constructs.

Comment: oh hmm let me try it :) thanks.

Comment: Okay I am definitely slow, but I obviously implemented it wrong `names=['mike','john']; 

    for (var i=1; i <= names.length; i++) {
        players.add({
            id: i,
            name: 'player_' + names,
            score: Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+20)
        });
    }` what its the proper way lol, with that I am getting `Name: player_mike,john - Points: 37`

Comment: I'd suggest you take a tour of JavaScript basics here http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics. Don't mean to sound rude, but I'm not sure how you work with Backbone without a basic understand of arrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your comments what i understood is, you need to write

```
names=['mike','john'];
for(var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    players.add({
        id: i,
        name: 'player_' + names[i],
        score: Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+20)
    });
}
```

just like other languages you have to give index number to get particular element from array.

Comment: i updated the answer, in initial code `i` starts with 1 but array indexes starts with 0 so i changed the loop